# print keys and values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary :

```
d = {'A': ['1', '2'],
     'B': ['1', '2'],
     'C': ['2', '2',],
     'D': ['1', '3']}
```

And I want to write print it like

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
D 1
D 2
```

Tried to write

```
for i in d.keys():
    for j in d2.values():
        print(i,j)
```

But in gives me ALL combinations not that I need.

Comment: Note that your expected output does not match exactly the values in your sample input.  For example, the values associated with key `D` should be 1 and 3, not 1 and 2.

Comment: Where is d2 coming from in this example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating the dictionary sorted by key.  Then, use each key to access the list of numbers for that key.

```
for i in sorted(d):
    for j in d[i]:
        print(i + ' ' + j)
```

This prints:

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 2
C 2
D 1
D 3
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go  -

```
d = {'A': ['1', '2'],
     'B': ['1', '2'],
     'C': ['2', '2',],
     'D': ['1', '3']}

for (k,v) in d.items():
    i=0
    while i < len(v):
        print(k,v[i])
        i= i+1
```

Comment: You could also simplify the inner loop to just `for inner_value in v: print(k, inner_value)` without needing an i.